# Android - Open settings activity using NFC

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

I'm trying to build an app that will automatically download an application. To do this, I already created an NFC tag to open a certail uel http://example.com/myapp.apk . My goal now is to also opens the application settings (where the user can check the install from unknown sources).

Until now, the only way I found to do this is using an app to read the tag (NFC Task launcher for instance) but I want to do this without needing any other app.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: SO what is the motivation behind this? AARs support downloads of apps from google play already.

Comment: I'm building a proprietary app that will be used within a company. These devices are not intended to download apps from google play. The thing is that when a new device arrives it must be configured manually  and the goal is to automatize part of the process (input the URL to download several APKs and open settings) to make it quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible to do?

Only by downloading the Android source code, adding some entries to the Setting's app's manifest to allow outsiders to hack into the app via NFC, and compiling the results into a ROM mod.

Only apps that opt into responding to NFC tags can be opened by NFC tags directly.